# What kind of contract should I use to hire people only in the case of future funding?

Tags: contract-law

I have to present a project for a new application to investors where I have to include the details of my team members.

Since the team is still incomplete I would like to be able to make agreements with external workers taken from the web and use their personal data, starting the employment relationship only in the case of a success financing.

Is there a legal form to make arrangements with a worker for a future activity, not paying them now but binding them to my project based on the contingency of future funding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of contract is pretty common when a general contractor is bidding on a project with binding subcontractor bids, usually called a binding bid or something like that. But, this kind of contract is usually not done for an employment relationship because you can't bind someone to a personal employment relationship (that would be indentured servitude and isn't legal).

You might consider a "letter of intent" or just informal discussions. You need a certain amount of trust when you're dealing with potential top level employees.